# ret->data = _malloc(ret->size + 8)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to compile on Microsoft visual studio 2013 on C++ a program written for linux 
( is a mix of C and C++ (#include .h) and I'm going to convert all in C++  to not be more confused !)

the statement:

```
ret->data = _malloc(ret->size + 8);
```

return the error:

> IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "unsigned char *"

please help

Comment: Don't use `malloc()` in c++.

Comment: The error is quite informative. What else do you need?

Comment: C is *not* a subset of C++! C code and C++ code are two very different things, you cannot expect one to work as the other.

Comment: As @BaummitAugen said, for example `int *new = malloc(sizeof(int));` is valid c, not valid c++ though.

Comment: What is `_malloc`? Is it anything like `malloc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c++ you need to explicitly cast `void *` to the target poitner type, so to fix your code

```
ret->data = static_cast<unsigned char *>(_malloc(ret->size + 8));
```

or, use `new`/`delete[]`

```
ret->data = new unsigned char[ret->size + 8];
```

Some notes,

1. You can't use `new`/`delete[]` if you will be using `realloc()` later.
2. You probably need to change your compiler to a c compiler, because that is clearly c code, not c++.

Perhaps the problem is the file extension, if you give the file a `.cpp` or `.cxx` extension it will be compiled as c++ code, so change it to `.c` and it should work.

Comment: @BaummitAugen sorry I really don't know the difference, I really do c coding mostly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used if you want to learn more. :)

Comment: Peculiar? GCC also has that: `-x c`. Otherwise just use the `.c` file extension to use the MS C compiler (again, just like GCC).

Comment: @cremno I didn't know that, I'll fix the answer. I just have been using linux for about 8yrs and didn't get to write many programs with Visual Studio, so I was based on what I've read online.